# docx4j html export with list

Tags: java, html, docx, docx4j

I have a problem with exporting a docx document to html with docx4j. My application cuts paragraphs out from several documents, then concatenates it into a single one, then exports it into html.

The problem is with the lists. The generated docx opens and the content I want is there (although it states that the document have errors and instead of a bullet list, there is a numbered one), but during html export i get the following error message:

**ERROR** *org.docx4j.model.PropertyResolver .getEffectivePPr line 635* - Couldn't find style: ListParagraph

I have listed the known styles and also checked in the StyleTree, and ListParagraph is there.

If I create a new PStyle and assign it to the problematic paragraph, the error is gone, but so is the list format. It becames a simple paragraph without bullets (as it should be). If I try to assign any other style than "Normal", I get the same error, only with other style name in the error message.

```
if (paragraphProp.getPStyle().getVal().equals("ListParagraph")) {
    listElements.add(paragraph);
```

Another strange thing is, that I can find paragraphs based on this style, but assigning the same style gets the error...meaning, the "if" above is working, paragraphs are added to the list, but this results in the error mentioned above (I've tried with List Paragraph written seperate, so that is not the problem):

```
PStyle style = new PStyle();
style.setVal("ListParagraph");
paragraphProp.setPStyle(style);
```

I also noticed, that there is only Normal and DocDefaults class names for paragraphs in the generated html.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try [docx4j-nightly-20130828.jar](http://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/docx4j-nightly-20130828.jar), which incorporates [a fix](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/commit/26ca4f1ec54e8c70c37ff50ad1b6f36064864321).

Comment: Thank you. It seems, that the problem with the list is gone, but I see that the HtmlExporterNG2 is deprecated. Now the html conversion does not work properly. Could you please show me a code snippet of a html conversion of a docx document with this new jar? Thank you very much!

Comment: See https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertOutHtml.java line 107, Docx4J.toHTML(htmlSettings, os, Docx4J.FLAG_NONE);

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I still seem to run into problems. Now the exporter says: Exception exporting package!

It worked before, but now the exception is:

Variable 'pPrNode' is multiply defined in the same scope.

I'm thinking, that maybe im doing something wrong when I copy paragraphs from the source document to my new one. Is there something I should consider while doing this?

Basicly I'm searching for specific text using p.toString() (I know its deprecated, but I only need to search in the text node), and I use deepcopy to put paragraphs into a list, which I then add to a new doc.

Comment: If I use Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_NONXSL then the conversion goes well, but there is no styling.

Comment: If you save the docx, then try to create HTML via XSLT from the docx freshly loaded, does it work?  If not, you can create another question, including a link to a docx which exhibits the issue.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it. Anyway, I will accept your answer, since you helped me a lot, thanks. ;)